# Show that a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients satisfying $f(x)=f(x^2+x+1)$ has even degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Updating this question with full problem statement from the source:

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If
>   $$f(x)=f(x^2 +x+1)$$
>   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, show that $f(x)$ is an even degree polynomial.

([original problem image (Question 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqpze.jpg))

Please, if possible, try to explain using tools a 12th standard student can understand.

Comment: Is there some reason for you to believe that $f$ is a polynomial in the first place?

Comment: As a first observation, a constant function such as $f(x)=5$ satisfies the property you describe and that is not an odd function, so it can't be exclusively odd.  This is not enough to prove that it is always purely even either however so more work needs to be done.

Comment: what do you know ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Is there some reason there is such an $f$ that is not constant?  Such equations can be hard to satisfy.

Comment: @RossMillikan: For any $x\ge0$, $x^2+x+1>x$, and therefore there are infinitely many $x>0$ with $f(x)=f(0)$. Thus if $f$ is not constant, it cannot be a polynomial, as any non-constant polynomial can give the same value only finitely many times.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri the question mentions f(x) to be a polynomial

Comment: @AbuShahid: Welcome to Math.SE! Thanks for clarifying the question by supplying its full statement. Note that the community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Please edit your question to include such details.

Comment: Then my answer (specifically the second part) shows that $f$ must be a degree $0$ polynomial, which has even degree.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$.
Partition $\Bbb R$ into equivalence classes via $x\sim y$ if and only if $x = g^k(y)$ or $y = g^k(x)$ for some $k$.

Define $f$ however you wish on each equivalence class, meaning that on each equivalence class, $f$ assumes a single value, but it can assume distinct values on different classes.
Then $f$ satisfies the hypotheses of the question.

Obviously, $f$ need not be continuous, much less a polynomial.
It's also easy to see that classes in general don't contain $x$ and $-x$, so $f$ need not be odd or even.

---

More generally, it's easy to see that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k>0$, then $f(x^2 + x + 1)$ is a polynomial of degree $2k$, and hence $f(x) - f(x^2+x+1)$ has degree $2k$ and therefore cannot be $0$ everywhere.

It follows that the only way for $f$ to be polynomial at all is for $f$ to be constant, that is, a degree $0$ polynomial.